# R foreach loop compare every row to every row

Tags: r, foreach

I would like to compare every row in a df to every other row in that same df (and compute some functions, too). I've managed to write a foreach loop, but it only compares every row to the last row.

Here's a minimal we of what I did so far:

```
# create toy df
ID <- c(345, 476, 234, 987, 123) # assign random id
Language <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee") # names of languages
Latitude <- c(-17, -25, 44, -8, 29) 
Longitude <- c(130, 29, -122, 120, -110)
sample <- data.frame(ID, Language, Latitude, Longitude)


sample
   ID Language Latitude Longitude
1 345       aa      -17       130
2 476       bb      -25        29
3 234       cc       44      -122
4 987       dd       -8       120
5 123       ee       29      -110


# foreach loop that should pair every language with every other
sample.rows <- nrow(sample)

loop <- foreach(i=1:(sample.rows-1),.combine=rbind) %do% {
   empty.pairs <- c()
   for(j in (i+1):sample.rows){
     pairs <- rbind(empty.pairs, c(i, j)) 
   }
  data.frame(Lang1 = sample$Language[pairs[,1]],
              Lang2 = sample$Language[pairs[,2]],
              i= pairs[,1],
              j= pairs[,2])
   }
```

which outputs the following:

```
loop
 Lang1 Lang2 i j
1    aa    ee 1 5
2    bb    ee 2 5
3    cc    ee 3 5
4    dd    ee 4 5
```

i.e. the loop only compares the first four lines to the last line, but I want it to compare all the row to all other rows, so e.g. language "aa" should be compared not only to "ee", but also "bb", "cc" and "dd". 
Any hints appreciated!

Comment: You are resetting empty.pairs on each loop.

Comment: If you know the size of the object you're creating, preallocate it and fill it rather than augmenting a null object.

Comment: @Dave2e: okay, so how do I avoid doing that?

Comment: @F.Privé: the real data has 2432 rows, so I don't think that's a viable solution... or did I misunderstand this?

Comment: @Dave2e thanks for following up! I get the exact same output though, so that doesn't seem to be the problem :-/

Comment: Replace `empty.pairs` with `pairs` in the above.  F. Privé use of the `expand.grid` is a more efficient  solution than nested loops.

Comment: this works, thank you! (point taken that nested loops aren't very efficient, but see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is a grid of all combination of languages. You can use `expand.grid`:

```
grid <- cbind(
  expand.grid(sample$Language, sample$Language),
  expand.grid(seq_len(sample.rows), seq_len(sample.rows))
)
names(grid) <- c("Lang1", "Lang2", "i", "j")
grid <- grid[grid[["j"]] > grid[["i"]], ]
```

PS: If you want to e.g. compute distances, using a matrix would be better than a data frame.

Comment: I accepted it because it answers the question I was asking - thanks for writing this out! I'm going to stick with the loop though, because I need to apply several functions (e.g. geographic distance of two lang) based on the original df and I don't see how I could do that with the grid.